# X (JS object with functions and state) refers to a value but is being used a type here

Tags: typescript

In the file `user.ts` I have the following code:

```js
export default {
  eventsTracked: {
  },

  loggedIn(): boolean {
    return !!readCookie("user_id")
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the available properties (etc.) automatically inferred elsewhere?

For example, in the file `window.d.ts` I would like to do

```js
import User from "user"

declare global {
  interface Window {
    user: User
  }
}
export {}
```

However, when I try that, I get the error:

```
2749: 'User' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here
```

What would you recommend I do?

My goal is that wherever I reference `window.user` in my code, it will be type-aware.

Comment: That should work, maybe you need to use a relative path? ./user. Global variables are evil, especially when they have names that are so damn likely to collide

Comment: @AluanHaddad The path is correct in the actual code — if it weren't I'd see the error "2307: Cannot find module `user`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yash Baheti pointed out, it is a good practice to create an actual type or interface and then create objects that implement it. However, if you really want typescript to infer automatically the type from your object you can use the `typeof` keyword.

In `user.ts`:

```
const user = {
  .. your object with properties/methods/ecc ...
} 

export type UserType = typeof user

export default user
```

In `window.d.ts`:

```
import { UserType } from 'user';

declare global {
    interface Window {
       user: UserType
    }
}
export {}
```

Note that unless each item in your user object is properly typed, typescript will infer a type that may not be correct for your case. I would suggest you to properly type everything

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend creating an interface for the object you are creating and using that. The `user.ts` file can look like this:

```
export interface User {
    eventsTracked: Record<string, string>;
    loggedIn: () => boolean;
}
const user: User = {
    eventsTracked: {},
    loggedIn() {
        return false
    }
}
export default user;
```

> [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is a utility type provided by TypeScript.

And in `window.d.ts` you can use it like this:

```
import { User } from 'user';

declare global {
    interface Window {
       user: User
    }
}
export {}
```

I can see a naming conflict here, but it's standard convention to have the interface names in PascalCase, rather than the [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) when using TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers do provide good advice, the minimum that you need to do to achieve this is simply to add the `typeof` keyword. No changes to `user.ts` are actually required.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    user: typeof User
  }
}
```